# PHP MVC load multiple controllers models and views in same page

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm currently designing my own MVC framework in PHP. I've read a lot about MVC frameworks and made one where the controller handles the models and renders the views, although this is not recommended.

The structure works as follows: The bootstrap class loads the proper controller, methods and variables based on the URL. It also initiates a maincontroller, mainmodel and mainview, which have some general functions. The controllers initiate their model and in the end render their template.

The problem is that I have 3 MVC objects. A top menu, a search bar and a table. I want these to be rendered on the same page. But since I let the controller do the rendering I can't render the three different parts in the same webpage. Do I need some kind of helper class, and if so how do I implement it the right way?

The url would be like: localhost/MyApp/grid.

Every controller contains this code:

```
$this->view->render(filepath/file.php)
```

Every template contains the code:

```
echo $this->data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm currently designing my own MVC framework in PHP.

Big mistake there, trust me - I tried. It does not end well.

> I've read a lot about MVC frameworks (..)

Even bigger mistake. Frameworks do not implement MVC. Therefore, whatever you read was just someone trying to sell their polished shit as gold.

> (..) and made one where the controller handles the models and renders the views (..)

Controller is not responsible for rendering templates (because I do not believe that you actually have views) and there are no plural "models".

`</rant>`

What you need is a proper templating engine. Try [twig](https://twig.symfony.com). Let the templating engine to handle the shared parts.

Comment: So what you're saying is, switch to something like Symfony or Laravel? I'll take a look at twig, thanks.

Comment: @IceEcold when did I say something so stupid as *"switch to something like Symfony or Laravel"*. I told you to try using Twig, which is a *standalone* composer package.

Answer (score 1):

There are some different concepts to handle this.

In one of my projects i split the html in templates and the view loads each area as it needs it.

For example something like:

```
$this->renderTemplate('page.header', $pageHeaderModel);
$this->renderTemplate('page.content.'.$viewKey, $pageContentModel);
$this->renderTemplate('page.footer', $pageFooterModel);
```

On every page the content model changes and the other stay the same.

Comment: Here is a working example from my code: https://github.com/JohnnyDevNull/wot-stats-search-engine/blob/master/app/view.php